# Unity & Steam VR Startup Errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

When starting with a clean project in Unity, I've created some very simple 3D geometry, which is a room without a ceiling.  I've included the SteamVR asset and drag in the camera prefab.

When I start the game, I get the following errors,

[image: Steam VR startup errors]

I'm using the latest version of Unity (2018.2.14f1) and whatever version of SteamVR that is on the Unity asset store.

The game runs, but with these errors, I'm not seeing my controllers for one, I'm sure lots more is broken but that's the first, most obvious thing.

Steam VR is running and "Ready" and the Oculus app is running as normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see some error that indicates this is coming from both the Editor and the plugin itself. Restart Unity then try again, If the error is still there, check if there is a sample scene included in the project. Use that as there might be some scripts missing in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems (the last 5) with the SteamVR Version 2.0.1 from the asset store. You have to initialize the VR Input in your Project.
Go to Window -> SteamVR Input (you can use the example settings to begin) and press safe and generate.
After that the Behaviour_Pose should be set on both controllers (see image) and you should see them again in your scene.

Pose Action should be set on both controller:
[image: Pose Action should be set on both controler]

Maybe you can find more help on this [thread about updating to the new SteamVR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686286/how-to-update-your-unity-project-input-to-steamvr-2-0).
Best of luck!