# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SteamVR_Trackedobject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had a error in playmode option in unity

Can u plz help me

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update your Unity project Input to SteamVR 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686286/how-to-update-your-unity-project-input-to-steamvr-2-0)